# How would I write multiple "if" conditions in one line in timber/twig?

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I have a situation where I would like to write multiple "if" condition in one line such as example: `{% if room_status == 'For Rent' and not 'Booked' %}` this is obviously not working but you get the picture of what I am trying to accomplish.

But have no idea how to write this other that doing this:

```
{% if room_status == 'For Rent'%}
  {% if room_status != 'Booked' %}
    {# <Then run some code here> #}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Twig *If* Documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html):

> For multiple conditions, `and` and `or` can be used:

```
{% if temperature > 18 and temperature < 27 %}
    <p>It's a nice day for a walk in the park.</p>
{% endif %}
```

So, in your case this should work:

```
{% if room_status == 'For Rent' and room_status != 'Booked' %}
    {# <Then run some code here> #}
{% endif %}
```

Although it seems to me that you don't really need the second check. The `room_status` variable can only contain one value, right? It can't be both 'For Rent' and 'Booked' at the same time, it's either one or the other.